# I have an error when doing the custom theme build

Tags: orocommerce

I have an error when doing the custom theme build, I get the following error when I run the following command bin/console gold:assets:build -- theme: https://i.postimg.cc/zBxLSXYP/Screenshot-20210928-175918.jpg

And the code I added was the following:

src/oro/Bundle/ThemeBundle/Resources/config/oro/Bundle.yml:

```
bundles:
    - { name: oroBundle/ThemeBundle/ThemeBundle, priority: 10 }
```

src/oro/Bundle/Bundle/ThemeBundle/Resources/views/layouts/theme/config/assets.yml.

```
styles:
  inputs:
      - bundles/ThemeBundle/theme/scss/settings/global-settings.scss
      - bundles/ThemeBundle/theme/scss/variables/top-bar-config.scss
      - bundles/ThemeBundle/theme/scss/styles.scss
  output: css/styles.css
```

src/oro/Bundle/ThemeBundle/Resources/views/layouts/theme/theme.yml

```
parent: default
logo: bundles/themeBundle/theme/images/logo.svg
icon: bundles/themeBundle/theme/favicons/favicon.ico
tag: My Company Marketplace
description: My Company Marketplace theme.
groups: [commerce]
```

src/oro/Bundle/ThemeBundle/oroThemeBundle.php:

```
<?php
namespace oroThemeBundle;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
class OroThemeBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

In the sccs files I have the following:

src/oro/Bundle/ThemeBundle/Resources/public/theme/scss/components/top-bar.scss:

```
/* @theme: theme; */

.topbar {
  background: $top-bar-background;
}
```

src/oro/Bundle/ThemeBundle/Resources/public/theme/scss/settings/_colors.scss:

```
/* @theme: theme; */

$custom-color-palette: (
  "primary": (
    "primary": #0165ad,
    "base": #fd302b,
    "light": #ff7a76,
    "dark": #ce0500,
  ),
);
$color palette: map_merge($color_palette, $custom_color_palette);
```

src/gold/Bundle/ThemeBundle/Resources/public/theme/scss/variables/top-bar-config.scss:

```
/* @theme: theme; */

$top-bar-font-size: 14px;
$top-bar-background: get-color('primary', 'main');
```

Comment: Please check the output of `php bin/console debug:container --parameter=kernel.bundles --format=json` command. Your bundle, `OroThemeBundle`, must be listed there.

Comment: My bundle is not shown in the list

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the directory structure and namespace mismatch.

With the current structure, you have to change the oroThemeBundle.php class namespace to `oro/Bundle/ThemeBundle`
and reuse it in the bundles.yml file

```yaml
bundles:
    - { name: oro/Bundle/ThemeBundle/OroThemeBundle, priority: 10 }
```

Also, pay attention that the PHP class name must match the filename, so the oroThemeBundle.php file should be renamed to `OroThemeBundle.php`.

This is forced by PSR-4 Autoloader standard: https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/